# Applying a generic template for a specific node

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a specific node I want to process:

```
<x:apply-templates select="Classification[@classificationScheme='urn:uuid:93606bcf-9494-43ec-9b4e-a7748d1a838d']/Slot[@name='authorRole']/ValueList/Value[text() = 'Reporting']/../../../Slot[@name='authorPerson']" />
```

Okay, what this gets me is the `authorPerson` slot for an author with role 'Reporting'.

But the value of the `authorPerson` is a more generic element and there will be author authors with `authorPerson` elements I am putting in other result elements.

What kind of match do I need for the template?

Just repeating:

```
<x:template match="Classification[@classificationScheme='urn:uuid:93606bcf-9494-43ec-9b4e-a7748d1a838d']/Slot[@name='authorRole']/ValueList/Value[text() = 'Reporting']/../../../Slot[@name='authorPerson']">
```

Doesn't seem right.

Note that the element I'm interested in is of type `Slot`, but this is basically a very simple key-value element with meaning only given by its attribute.

Would it be sufficient to say:
`<x:template match="Slot[@name='authorPerson']">` ??

Comment: Okay, my simple approach did indeed work. I can just reference `Slot` for my template match and it's all good. Sorry to waste your time. :)

Comment: Would you considering officially answering your own question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was sufficient to say `<x:template match="Slot[@name='authorPerson']">`. :)